# Use a parameter in SSRS for table_name

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I have scoured the internet for options and the only one I have found that can do it is by using a $Proc however I am trying to avoid that.

I would think it would be pretty simple to use a parameter to select a different table depending on what the user chooses from a drop down.

Here it is:
- There are two tables the report needs to use, 
    * some_table_CY (current year table)
    * some_table_STLY (same time last year table)

So I created a parameter that gives the user the option to select "Current_Year" or "Last_Year", depending on which one the user chooses the parameter would then be used in the select statement, something like this: `"SELECT * FROM :pReportVersion"`

However, it is not working.  I need it to do this, not using a union since unioning these two tables causes HUGE performance issues and the query takes more than 4 hours to run which is not acceptable for a report that users need on request.

(This is querying oracle)

Comment: Sounds like something that could require dynamic SQL, but I'm no expert in it..  You'd probably have to pass something like `some_table_CY` or `some_table_STLY` to the query and build your select like `DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableChoiceParameter` and then `EXEC @sql`.  [Documentation](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Dataset expression and set it to:

="SELECT * FROM " & Parameters!ReportVersion.Value

[image]

For longer queries you may need to wrap each line with quotes, append with an ampersand and add a line feed:

```
="SELECT * " & VBCLRLF & 
 "FROM " & Parameters!ReportVersion.Value & VBCRLF &
 "WHERE FIELD1 > 10 " & VBCRLF & 
 "AND FIELD2 = 'YES' "
```

Comment: The issue I ran into with using it like this, with IF statements, the query itself is much larger than a single line (about 2000 lines) and to use it as a function it errors out when it isn't on a single line.

Comment: I added some code showing how I added multiple lines in a Dataset Expression. I think I used Notepad++ to replace the linefeed ( `/n` ) with `" & VBCLRLF & /n "` .

Answer (score 0):

you can still use the union..

Say you have a parameter called `@year`

set the available values to the following (specify values)

> current year for label and 1 for value
>
> last year for label and 2 for value

Then your dataset can be something like this:

```
select * from some_table_CY 
where @year = 1

union all

select * from some_table_LY 
where @year = 2
```

Comment: What I mean about the union is, even when I do something like that it takes more than an hour.  I tried this and it doesn't work in a reasonable amount of time:


SELECT 1 FROM (
 SELECT * FROM [schema_name].[table_name_CY] WHERE :pReportVersion = 'CY'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM [schema].[table_name_STLY] WHERE :pReportVersion = 'STLY'
       )

Comment: The views are massive and not the fastest, executing each view individually only takes a minute, however any type of union or join causes it to keep going forever as if there is something broken which is why I was wanting a parameter that could select the table itself.